# Google map in listview item

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to put map in listview item.I want to implements like this!
![enter image description here][1]

I extends FragmentActivity
MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maplist);
    mlayoutInflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.maplist);


    baseAdapter = new BaseAdapter(){

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            if(convertView == null){
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mlayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mapcontent, null);
                viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                if (aMap == null) {
                    aMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                }
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            }else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
                viewHolder.textView.setText(data[position]);

            return convertView;

        }


    };

    listView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
```

mapcontent.xml,here is the every item I add  to listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"  >  
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text"


    />
</LinearLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

error log

```
Binary XML file line #18: Duplicate id 0x7f09003d, tag null,
```

Comment: Thanks in advance,I have this problem for a few days,so I need help

Answer (score 0):

Google might fixed this issue in v21. You could try to update your support library to v21.

For older support library, you could try to override the onDestoryView() method for your mapFragment with the following code:

```
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = (fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```